# Is it possible to reverse engineer the values of a and b in floating point arithmetic error, like (a -b) == 0.499 when it should have been 0.5?

Tags: floating-point, precision

In my application I'm calculating elapsed time (a-b) and I got `0.4999978542327881` (printed by python) which I guess it's really `0.4999978542327880859375` if it was not rounded by python for printing.

I do believe that `a-b` should have been `0.5` **if I did it with pen and paper**. My guess is that I'm getting `0.4999978542327880859375` due to limitations of float number representation of `a`, `b` and the result value.

I'm fine with the the error, and I account for tolerances.

My question is really:  **Is there a procedure to get `a` and `b`?** I mean I want to get two decimal numbers `a` and `b` that when subtracting using pen and paper gives `0.5` and then using floating point arithmetic (IEEE 754) will give me `0.4999978542327880859375`. I can print `a` and `b` but I can't really reproduce the error since it depends on the elapsed time.

For example, let's say that I have `(a-b) = 0.19999999999999998` and I know it should have been `0.2` if I was using **plain "human" arithmetic** instead of floating point arithmetic. I would like to reverse engineering the values of `a` and `b` to be `0.3` and `0.1` since I know that `0.3-0.1==0.2` in regular arithmetic but `0.3-0.1==0.19999999999999998` in floating point arithmetic since `0.1` closest representation is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`.

The procedure does not need to produce a unique values for `a` and `b`. A list of all possible `(a,b)` pairs  would be even more useful, that way I can search for the most suitable example since I know the approximate time when this happen and `a` and `b` are timestamps in seconds since the epoch as float. For example, in this particular instance I know that both `a` and `b` must be between `1704964314.0` ('2024-01-11T09:11:54.000+00:00')  and `1704964316.0` ('2024-01-11T09:11:56.000+00:00')

I'm interested in both the particular case for `0.4999978542327881` but also in getting a general procedure to get examples for particular results. why? Because I want to provide an example of the input values for each floating point "error" I found in the logs of my application (for the github issues).

Comment: *"...due to limitations of float number representation of `a` and `b`"* **And/or** limitations storing the result value. Usually "and." :-) (Lurkers: [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken#588014))

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I doubt you can work backward from `0.4999978542327881` and the fact that in pure math it would have been `0.5` to the original values of `a` and `b`. I strongly suspect there are multiple values for `a` and `b` that would have that result.

Comment: Are you sure you really got precisely `0.4999978542327881`? That value isn't representable in IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point (if that's what your system uses). Beware that when you convert a binary floating point value to string (e.g., for output), most environments round the output to only enough digits to differentiate the underlying represented value from its representable neighbours. [Here's](https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point) a good site for seeing the actual value held for both 32-bit and 64-bit IEEE-754 floating point.

Comment: Multiple values for `a` and `b` would be ok for my case, I only need examples they don't need to be unique. I can actually bound `a` and `b` since they are really epoch-seconds and I know  both a and b should be between 2024-01-11T9:11:54.000Z and 2024-01-11T9:11:56.000Z

Comment: No, I guess 0.4999978542327881 is not the right value either, I'm using python in this case , as you point out there is some rounding done when it's printed. so I guess the problem is even harder.

Comment: There is no general way to determine from a floating-point arithmetic result what the real-number arithmetic result would have been. If there were, the floating-point arithmetic would have produced that result, as it was designed to be as good as its characteristics allowed. If you have particular constraints, such as that the real result must be representable as a decimal numeral with a known number of digits and only a limited amount of rounding error may have occurred, then determining the real result may be possible. However, you have not provided any information about such constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are many `a, b,` combos, yet we can deduce some hints.

A first step is to perform the analysis using non-decimal notation.  It is certainly more insightful given the binary nature of floating point values.

The below prints `0x1.ffff7p-2 0x1.ffff7p-2` which hints that the issue *may* be restricted to `float` values and not `double`.

```
int main() {
  double d = 0.4999978542327880859375;
  printf("%a\n%a\n", d, (float) d);
  return 0;
}
```

Adding the below code, we see `0x1.ffff7p-2` is 72 `float`s away from 0.5.  This distance for a simple math subtraction implies the `a - b` distance involves a value *about* 72 times greater than 0.5.  (Hand waving the math here.)

```
  unsigned count = 0;
  while (d < 0.5) {
    d = nextafterf(d, 0.5);
    count++;
  }
  printf("%u\n", count);
```

Beyond that, we are getting into more *ifs* and really need more info to proceed much more.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to use SMT solvers, which can solve constraints over floating-point numbers. See [this paper](http://www.philipp.ruemmer.org/publications/smt-fpa.pdf) and [smtlib FP logic](https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml) for an overview.

SMT-solvers can be scripted from many languages, including Python. See https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm for an overview. I'll use Haskell's [SBV](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv) library here, since I'm most familiar with it.

The idea is to use a "larger" type to simulate real-arithmetic, and then do the computation over a "smaller" type to simulate machine-arithmetic. (SMT solvers can also reason about mathematical reals, but when you put reals and floats together, they suffer from complexity issues. So, it's best to avoid such mix-and-match style problems.)

To be precise, I'll use IEEE-doubles to model "real" arithmetic, and IEEE-floats to model "machine" arithmetic. (I also tried with using 128-bit floats and doubles respectively, but I don't think you can observe such differences in that model: Doubles have way too much granularity. So far as I know Python always uses doubles, so it's a bit confusing as to why you're seeing differences like this; but perhaps there are other constants involved; or you might be getting fooled by what's "printed" as opposed to what's the actual internally stored number. I'll side-step that discussion for now.)

Based on this, one can code the constraints like this, asking the SMT solver to give us 5 such results:

```hs
import Data.SBV

findPairs :: IO ()
findPairs = print =<< p
 where p = allSatWith z3{allSatMaxModelCount = Just 5} $ do
             a <- sDouble "a"
             b <- sDouble "b"

             constrain $ a .>= 1704964314 .&& a .<= 1704964316
             constrain $ b .>= 1704964314 .&& b .<= 1704964316
             constrain $ a - b .== 0.5

             let aF = toSFloat sRNE a
                 bF = toSFloat sRNE b

             constrain $ aF - bF ./= 0.5
```

This might be a bit hard to read unless you're familiar with Haskell; but essentially we're getting two double-values, in the range you specified, then we convert them to floats and state that the difference is not `0.5`. The way the SMT solvers work, you simply state the constraints, and it finds you the values that satisfy them.

When I run the above, I get:

```
*Main> findPairs
Solution #1:
  a = 1.7049643147382817e9 :: Double
  b = 1.7049643142382817e9 :: Double
Solution #2:
  a = 1.7049643147382813e9 :: Double
  b = 1.7049643142382813e9 :: Double
Solution #3:
  a = 1.7049643149726563e9 :: Double
  b = 1.7049643144726563e9 :: Double
Solution #4:
  a = 1.7049643147226563e9 :: Double
  b = 1.7049643142226563e9 :: Double
Solution #5:
  a = 1.704964314856312e9 :: Double
  b = 1.704964314356312e9 :: Double
Found 5 different solutions.
```

You can ask the system to print more than 5, print it in different formats, including the bit-layout if you like.

But long story short, one way to "reverse-engineer" such problems is to use SMT-solvers, put the constraints, and let it figure out what the original inputs might be. If you have a custom algorithm to find such numbers it'd be faster to use it, but SMT-solvers can act as a Swiss-army knife to solve arbitrary constraints when you don't have a good algorithm to start with.